# kendoEditor doesn't appear

Tags: kendo-ui

Here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="kendo_UI.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/kendo/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Styles/kendo/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <textarea id="editor" rows="10" cols="30"> </textarea>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#editor").kendoEditor();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But textarea appears without kendoEditor :-(

What's wrong?

Thank you!

And no more details ;-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kendo UI doesn't work with jQuery 1.9.x.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382884/issues-with-kendoui-and-jquery-1-9-0) You need to include jQuery 1.8.2. More info can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/javascript-dependencies#jquery-version).