# Can JQuery UI Mobile and Kendo UI Mobile co-exist in one project?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, icenium

Has anyone tried this before in Icenium or in regular HTML 5 project? Is there possible problem if we try to build our core project based on this two libraries?

Comment: there is absolutely no problem with that..

Comment: The question is too broad, but one thing that may be of help, should you decide to go that way: most Kendo UI Mobile widgets *need* an active Kendo UI Mobile application instance, and should reside in mobile views in order to function properly.

Comment: @underdog how can the question be too broad its an yes or no question...if yes how it can co exist if not why not?thats all I am looking for..

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan have you done taht?if yes how?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you are looking for. However, here's a [link](http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/build-apps-with-kendo-ui-mobile) that you can take a look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course yes as it is one of the dependency of Kendo UI.

A good way to check what is the "best" jQuery version for Kendo UI is to see what version is used on online demos.

Referring the following link to check the required JavaScript libraries and their version:

[JavaScript files used by Kendo UI](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/javascript-dependencies)

```
Note: Registering a new jQuery instance after the Kendo UI script files will delete all Kendo UI jQuery plugins and Javascript errors will occur.
```

Comment: so jquery ui mobile and kendo ui mobile cant exist in one project?

Comment: it can exists but the compatible version only. Not latest.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Kendo UI Mobile and jQuery Mobile are largely incompatible. Using both libraries in the same project can cause some unexpected behaviour...I also have added a thread which explains issues while using them both in one project.. [Issues with KendoUI and jQuery 1.9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382884/issues-with-kendoui-and-jquery-1-9-0)